# Output category list inside array

Tags: php, array, categories

I need to output information about each of my post categories in this array, but I'm having trouble figuring out how.

I need to output each category as an array (See examples) under the `values` option with the following information;

`'label' => 'CATEGORY NAME'`
`'values' => 'CATEGORY ID'`

```
array(
    'param_name'  => 'ids',
    'settings'    => array(
        'multiple' => true,
        'values'   => array( 
            // EXAMPLE
            array( 'label' => 'Abrams', 'value' => 1, 'group' => 'category' ),
            // EXAMPLE
            array( 'label' => 'Brama', 'value' => 2, 'group' => 'category' )
        ),
    ),
),
```

I've tried using a `foreach` `get_categories()` loop inside the array but apparently PHP doesn't like that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you need this information inside post object right?

Comment: @sonalip3 no. This is inside a custom function

Comment: Why doesn't get_categories() work?

Comment: @Svartbaard because I need to output the data in a specific format `array( 'label' => '[CATEGORY NAME]', 'value' => [CATEGORY ID], 'group' => 'category' )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like the following. Notice that the hide_empty argument is set to false.

```
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'id',
    'hide_empty'=> false,
);

$cats = get_categories($args);

foreach ($cats as $cat) {
    // Your code to populate new array here
}
```

And then assign your newly created array to values.

Comment: So in place of `'values' => array(...)` I'd put `'values' => $cats`?

Comment: That was my thought process yes. Populate the array the way you need it first and assign it to values.

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't output any information.

Comment: Try the following and see what it does:    

 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($cats);
 echo '</pre>';

 foreach ($cats as $cat) {
  echo $cat->name;
 }

I think the reason you didnt get results is due to the hide_empty argument.

Comment: It outputs the default list of data that `get_categories` outputs. I need to use certain values out of this data, in another array

Comment: Yes. So loop through the categories and build your new array with the values you need.

Comment: Awesome, glad to have helped.